# How to get PyCharm to format a JSON file

Tags: json, intellij-idea, pycharm

When I create a `.json` file in PyCharm and put in some JSON, I'm expecting it to format it as per the format shown under `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Code Style` `>` `JSON`.

But instead, my code stays as it is - e.g. more than one JSON key value pair on the same line, like this:

```json
{"just a test": "does this work","this should format": "but it doesn't"}
```

How can I make it so that when I open a `.json` file with PyCharm, it's nicely formatted?

I have checked that `.json` files are associated in the editor -> file types dialogue, and the editor tab correctly has the JSON icon, so PyCharm knows it's a JSON file.

Is there a key combination I have to hit to get it to format prettily or something?

Comment: My file is with .json extension. I clicked on Code -> Reformate Code then I see a pretty JSON.

Answer (score 115):

Ah, it doesn't auto-format it. If I paste in non-formatted JSON, it stays non-formatted. But if I press <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on windows, it formats it nicely.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Is it possible when I have finished the changes remove the enters and the unnecessary spaces to get back the compressed file?

Comment: worked for me !

Comment: To be clear ALT in Mac is `Option` so it is `option + command + l`

Comment: Annoyingly CTRL + ALT + L is the shortcut to lock my screen on Linux Mint. 

So I added a secondary Keymap in Pycharm:

Settings -> Keymap -> Find "Reformat code" -> Right click -> Add Keyboard Shortcut -> ALT + L

Comment: It works, and it's also available from the menu under `Code` -> `Reformat Code`.

Answer (score 10):

`Option(alt) + CMD + L` worked like magic on Mac

Answer (score 3):

Alt + Shift + L on Linux.

You can check your shortcut by looking at Code -> Reformate Code menu item.

Comment: For me on Pycharm 2022.1.4 PRO + linux mint, pressing Alt + Shift + L brings up the "Load Context" menu in Pycharm.

Comment: Well, for me it's working on PyCharm 2022.3.1 on Kubuntu. What combination do you have, @ChrisS ?

Comment: by default (annoyingly) it's CTRL + ALT + L - which locks the desktop :D I had to add in a custom keymap for it. So many flavours...so many configs :)

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl + Alt + L on windows works for me. Hope that adds to this.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Alt + L on Ubuntu worked for me